# Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute related error

Tags: c#, .net

i have 1 c# console appln,it executes any script file by using Process.Start() method. i provide script file path to `Process1.StartInfo.FileName`.My script file can be of any type (.vbs ,ps1 etc) . I m also passing String  to script by using instruction `p.StartInfo.Arguments`. When script file executed it should retrun string back to c# application. This returned string can be read by setting `Process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true`,But for using this instruction i need to set `Process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false`.
 When i run this i m getting error as "The specified executable is not a valid Win32 application".
 i think this may be because of, when i set `Process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false`, my appln dont know which .exe to be used to execute script file.

on the other hand if i provide exe path to `StartInfo.FileName` and script file path to `StartInfo.Argument` then i m not getting error. 
For Example:i want to execute powershell script and i set following properties as `P1.StartInfo.FileName = "location of powershell.exe"` and `p1.startInfo.Argument =".ps1 script file path"`, in this case i m not getting error.

problem is i dont know in advance,which type of script i m going to execute.also cant find out locations of .exe file for executing script file on different diffrent m/c. So is it possible to execute diffrent type of script files from same common c# appln and also read output returned by scripts?

here is my code

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Diagnostics;
 using System.Collections;
 namespace process_csharp
 {
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
        String path = null;
        //this will read script file path 
        path = Console.ReadLine();

        //this string is passed as argument to script
        string s = "xyz";

        Process p = new Process();          
        p.StartInfo.FileName= path;         
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = s;                     
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;      

        p.Start();
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
      }

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for the script type and read output from their own engine;

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = Console.ReadLine();
        string parameter = Console.ReadLine();
        string enginePath;
        switch (Path.GetExtension(path).ToLowerInvariant())
        {
            case ".ps1":
                enginePath = "powershell.exe";
                break;
            case ".vbs":
                enginePath = "cscript.exe";
                break;
            default:
                throw new ApplicationException("Unknown script type");
        }

        string scriptPath = path;
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = enginePath;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", scriptPath, parameter);
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.Start();
        Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: :i want pass string to script,how can i do this?

Comment: just append your string to `process.StartInfo.Arguments`, edited the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code instead:

```
string path = @"C:\mypsscript.bat";
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = path;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "xyz";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.Start();
Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
Console.ReadKey();
```

For the sakes of debugging I have created a batch file with the code:

```
echo %1
```

When I run the above code I get:

```
xyz
```

So that seems to work fine. Try using a batch file like this and see if it works, if it does it may be an association with powershell scripts that isn't working, which we can fix later.

Comment: @Bail C: i m getting error when i use  P1.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\mypsscript.ps1". Error:The specified executable is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: i m getting this error just beacuse of "p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;" instruction, whether i want to redirect output or not.

Comment: @sailer I have rewritten my answer after you posted your code, try this to do some debugging.

Comment: @Bail C:ur code and my code also works fine for batch file. But not working fo r .ps1 and .vbs files. 
My .ps1 file contains only single line "Write-Output "Hello world"

Comment: @sailer Hmm, thats strange, I'm not sure why that doesn't work tbh, sorry. Wait and see if anyone else has an answer to this. If nothing else, at least we know batch files work :) just not powershell and vb for whatever reason.